# nodejs mysql connection pool keeps re-initializing after every require statement

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

I have multiple modules which require my custom PromisifiedMySQL.js module.  I am trying to use a connection pool from the NodeJS mysql library.

I tried setting a variable called connectionPool to hold the initialized pool. However it seems that for every module that imports my PromisifiedMySQL.js file it attempts to initialize a new pool instance.

I want ONLY one pool instance to be created which is contained inside PromisifiedMySQL.js

Why is my connectionPool not keeping its state properly?

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
let connectionPool = null;


const initializePool = ()=>{
  if(isLiveEnv()){
    connectionPool = createLivePool();
  }
  else if(isDevEnv()){
    connectionPool = createDevPool();

  }
}



if(connectionPool === null){
  console.log(connectionPool === null);
  console.log('init pool!');
  initializePool();
}


let query = (sql, args) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      getConnection().then(con => {
        con.query(sql,args,(err,result) => {
          if(err) {
            con.release();
            reject(err);
          }
          else{
            con.release();
            resolve(result);
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err =>{
        reject(err);
      })
    })
} // end query.
```

My export look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  query:query
}
```

Where query gets a connection from the pool, runs the query and releases the connection.

If I have module1.js and module2.js require('./Promisified.js') then 
it actually makes two pools even though after the first one is created I set 
connectPool is be non-null;

Comment: I've tried also making a class with everything static and doing module.exports = PromisifiedMySQL ;    The same issue occurs,  the state seems to be getting lost.

Comment: Did you tried the Singleton pattern?

Comment: I think it might be because I am running several NodeJS instances.  (each in its own process) and they can't share state,  so each one has its own connection pool.